# Departure card date is 17 May; non-b visa has date of 15 May: Do I pay overstay?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, thailand, overstaying

My Thailand Non-Immigrant B Visa's expiration date is on the 15th of May and on my departure card the date is stamped the 17th of May.

Do I pay for an overstay since my Non-Immigrant B visa date expired yesterday, but my departure card date is stamped the 17th of May?

Comment: @Ricky if the answer is correct, can you mark it as correct please?

Answer (score 2):

## No overstay in the OP' case :)

**2 separate dates:**

1. **`Visa expiration date:`** [15 May 2017]  the date in which the visa expires.  So to use that specific visa, you must enter on or before the expiration date listed on the visa.
2. **`Permission to Stay date:`** [17 May 2017] The date in which the entrant must physically exit the country via border immigration checkpoint (or extended at a local immigration office). Usually the permission to stay stamp will have both the *entry date* and the *exit by date* stamped or printed in the passport and/or on some type of arrival/departure slip affixed to the passport.

`Permission to stay` is what counts after you enter any country....

OP must leave Thailand ***`before`***  **`23:59:59 on 17 May 2017`** to avoid overstay charges.  Most land borders close before that time....local immigration offices typically work 08:00-17:00; don't wait until the last second :D

---

#### Related FYIs

**1)** The easiest way to remember this is that you usually acquire a **visa** *BEFORE* entering a country.  The **permission to stay** is acquired when you are stamped in by border immigration OR `extended` in-country at designated gov't [immigration] office.

**2)** If you hear cases where someone is doing a so-called `border run` or `visa run`, it is usually because they either:

- have a multiple entry (ME) visa,
- entering under the Visa Exempt scheme, or
- are acquiring a new visa from a [nearby] Thai Embassy/Consulate.

In either case, technically they are exiting the country (Thailand) >> entering and exiting a different country >> entering the desired country (Thailand) again.  When it is all done on the same day, it is casually known as an `Out-In` entry. (You go out and come back in the same day)

---

**3)** Bonus:  Some Thai international airport border ***may*** waive overstay fine if you are only overstay < 24 hours.  I would not recommend relying on that though.

Comment: @KateGregory was supposed to be FYI (For Your Information).  I made the edit :D